# Language store view Url without slash return page with error message "no CMS page"

Tags: magento2

I have a multistore with different languages, i have set the langue code to be in the URL, so
https://www.domain.com/en_ca gives page with this message

```
There was no Home CMS page configured or found.
```

https://www.domain.com/en_ca/ gives the correct CMS home page.

https://www.domain.com/fr_ca and https://www.domain.com/fr_ca/ works

The problem appears for https://www.domain.com/fr_ca and sometimes for https://www.domain.com/en_ca